# Problem with package "tools" after Update

Tags: tools, auto-pst-pdf

I have a problem with the package `tools` after an update of MiKTeX 2.9.6670 64 bit. See the following MWE in which I use the package `auto-pst-pdf`. While compiling, I'm getting this window:

[image]

After clicking `Install`, the end of the log-file looks like this:

[image]

MWE (TeXnicCenter LaTeX->PDF):

```
  \documentclass{standalone}
  \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
  \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
  \usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
  \usepackage{pst-all}
  \usepackage{auto-pst-pdf}

  \begin{document}

  \begin{pspicture}[showgrid=false](0,0)(1,1)
  \psdot(0.5,0.5) 
  \end{pspicture}

  \end{document}
```

No PDF file in the end ... So what could be the reason I can't use `auto-pst-pdf` any more? Is there a problem in the `tools` package? Before sunday/monday, everything worked fine! Any solutions?

Comment: there may be a packaging error, let me test something...

Comment: sorry there appears to be an error in the build script `.tex` got generated but dropped from the zip file.

Comment: There is no .tex in the tools-package and I don't have it. But miktex doesn't try to install the tools package in my case -- the compilation works without problems. Synchronize your package database (miktex console, task menu -> refresh database).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry. A packaging error meant that the file `.tex` didn't get in to the `latex-tools.tds.zip` file in the last release. It isn't clear to me why that affects your document, but anyway sorry about that, I have submitted a corrected zip file to ctan within the last few minutes, it may take a few days to work its way through the system and appear in distributions.